# jQuery one click run function twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I'm writing a quiz game using jQuery, but when I click the button in question2, it will skip question3 somehow, the click event run twice by itself.
I'm so confused and struggle, please help!
any inputs appreciated.
Thanks

[JS Code]

```
function showQuestions() {
$("#title").text(questions[counter].title);
$("#answer-1")
.show()
.text(questions[counter].answer1.name)
.one("click", function() {
userChoice.push(questions[counter].answerl1.isCorrect);
getResult();
});
$("#answer-2")
.show()
.text(questions[counter].answer2.name)
.one("click", function() {
userChoice.push(questions[counter].answer2.isCorrect);
getResult();
});
$("#answer-3")
.show()
.text(questions[counter].answer3.name)
.one("click", function() {
userChoice.push(questions[counter].answer3.isCorrect);
getResult();
});
$("#answer—4")
.show()
.text(questions[counter].answer4.name)
.one("click", function() {
userChoice.push(questions[counter].answer4.isCorrect);
getResult();
});
}
function getResult() {
if (userChoice[counter]) {
$("#result")
.show()
.text("Correct!");
getResult();
} else {
$("#result")
.show()
.text("Wrong!");
scores —= 10;
gemeStart();
}
}
```

Comment: Please put the code into the question. Not behind a link

Comment: Whenever the game (re)starts, **new listeners are added for the answers**. So, you will end up with _several_ listeners after a while, _all_ running when the elements are clicked. This means that the answers are getting pushed into the array multiple times.

Comment: You should set up the listeners once outside of the game reset function, using `.on` instead of `.one`. Or, alternatively, remove the old listener before setting the new one, using `$('#answer1').off('click').on('click', ...)` for example.

Comment: oh, dear. you guys are amazing! off("click") works fine fore me. thanks you so much! I've stuck on it for hours!!

Comment: thanks @evolutionxbox I will post source code directly next time.
this's my very first time to raise the question here,
I just wonder how did you exact my code from the image I post, it's almost impossible to me.